# Finding difference from json output

Tags: python, json, xml, csv

I have 2 files in 2 different formats i.e (.csv & .xml). I have written the program in python to fetch the ip address,Qid,Port from the both files. I have redirected the output in json format to a file. I need help in finding the difference from the json output by giving 2 ip addresses as input and find similarity and difference of qid's and ports between 2 ip addresses. This is my code.

```
#! python
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import sys
import json
import csv
import os

def CSV(file):
    os.chdir('C:\\Users\\sraina\\Desktop\\tool_project')
    scan = file
    f1 = open(scan)
    csvReader = csv.reader(f1)
    csvData = list(csvReader)
    length = len(csvData)
    for i in range(8,length-1):
        try:
            a = csvData[i][0]
            b = csvData[i][5]
            c = csvData[i][9]
            Nfile = open('jscan','a')
            dump = {u"IP":a, u"QID": b, u"Port": c}
            d =  (json.dumps(dump, indent= 4))
            Nfile.write(d)
            Nfile.close()

        except:
            print  "\nThe row was empty or something went wrong while reading data from CSV..."

    f1.close
def xml(file):
    os.chdir('C:\\Users\\sraina\\Desktop\\tool_project')
    scan = file
    f = open(scan)
    tree = ET.parse(f)
    for node in tree.iter('*'):
        if node in tree.iter('IP'):
            a = "IP is "+ str(node.attrib.get("value"))
        if node in tree.iter('VULNS'):
            x = "********Vulns*********"
        if node in tree.iter('CAT'):
            b = "Port is " + str(node.attrib.get("port"))
        if node in tree.iter('VULN'):
            c = "Vuln Qid is " + str(node.attrib.get("number"))
            Nfile = open('jscan','a')
            dump = {u"V": x,u"IP": a, u"Port": b, u"Qid": c}
            d1 = (json.dumps(dump, indent=4))
            Nfile.write(d1)
            Nfile.close()
        if node in tree.iter('INFOS'):
            x1 = "********Infos*********"
        if node in tree.iter('CAT'):
            b1 = "Port is " + str(node.attrib.get("port"))
        if node in tree.iter('INFO'):
            c1 = "Info Qid is "+ str(node.attrib.get("number"))
            Nfile = open('jscan','a')
            dump = {u"IG": x1,u"IP": a, u"Port": b1, u"Qid": c1}
            d2 = (json.dumps(dump, indent=4))
            Nfile.write(d2)
            Nfile.close()

        if node in tree.iter('PRACTICES'):
            x2 = "********Practice************"
        if node in tree.iter('CAT'):
            b2 = "Port is " + str(node.attrib.get("port"))
        if node in tree.iter('PRACTICE'):
            c2 = "Practice Qid is "+ str(node.attrib.get("number"))
            Nfile = open('jscan','a')
            dump = {u"P": x2,u"IP": a, u"Port": b2, u"Qid": c2}
            d3 = (json.dumps(dump, indent=4))
            Nfile.write(d3)
            Nfile.close()
    f.close()

def JSON(file):
    for i in range(5):
        print "Enter Your file"
        file = raw_input()
        if os.path.isfile(file):
            if file.endswith('.csv'):
                CSV(file)
            elif file.endswith('.xml'):
                 xml(file)
            else:
                  print "file should be in xml or csv format"

        elif  file == "e":
            sys.exit()
        else:
            print "maybe file doesnt exists"




def main():
    os.chdir('C:\\Users\\sraina\\Desktop\\tool_project')
    file = ('new')
    JSON(file)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

JSON output looks like:

```
 {
    "IP": "10.10.36.45", 
    "Port": "1521", 
    "QID": "20046"
}{
    "IP": "10.10.36.45", 
    "Port": "", 
    "QID": "19129"
}{
    "IP": "10.10.36.45", 
    "Port": "", 
    "QID": "19226"
}{
    "IP": "10.10.36.45", 
    "Port": "1521", 
    "QID": "19221"
}{
    "IP": "10.10.35.85", 
    "Port": "", 
    "QID": "370658"
}{
    "IP": "10.10.35.19", 
    "Port": "", 
    "QID": "236554"
}{
    "IP": "10.10.34.146", 
    "Port": "", 
    "QID": "370658"
}{
    "IP": "10.10.34.131", 
    "Port": "", 
    "QID": "370658"
}{
    "IP": "10.10.33.182", 
    "Port": "", 
    "QID": "370658"
}{
    "IP": "10.10.33.172", 
    "Port": "", 
    "QID": "370658"
}{
    "IP": "10.10.33.137", 
    "Port": "", 
    "QID": "370658"
}{
    "IP": "10.10.31.99", 
    "Port": "", 
    "QID": "236554"
}{
    "IP": "10.10.31.97", 
    "Port": "", 
    "QID": "236554"
}{
    "IP": "10.10.31.129", 
    "Port": "", 
    "QID": "236554"
}{
    "IP": "10.10.25.38", 
    "Port": "", 
    "QID": "370658"
}{
    "IP": "10.10.24.85", 
    "Port": "", 
    "QID": "370658"
}{
    "IP": "10.10.24.182", 
    "Port": "", 
    "QID": "370658"
}
```

Comment: your json output is not valid json, you can check online how to correct the json  and paste it again

Comment: This is the output which i am getting while redirecting it to a file. What is invalid in the output and how can i correct it. Please suggest.

Comment: if you paste the json output here https://jsonlint.com/ and validate it, you will find this is not a valid json, so it wont be parsed with json module.

Comment: you have two options 1) either write the output in a valid json format, you need to alter the code writing the output 2) Treat the output file as normal file and see if you can create some nested dictionary to parse the data